# Is there any problem to test the following topology without load?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, converter, power-factor-correction

I've implemented the following PFC boost 80W converter. Is there any problem to test the following topology without load?

[image]

Comment: Depends what you're trying to test, exactly. It may well appear to work fine until you load it.

Comment: Note that PFC's are "weird" in that they don't bench-test well.  What I mean is, you may be tempted to first power it from a variac and source resistance, such as a light bulb to thwart any would-be failures.  But the PFC will draw full current at it's lowest starting voltage (to charge C6) so this ends up oscillating with a lamp in place.  Best bet is to set  the variac at the circuit's lowest operable volts (say 90VAC) and just switch it on.  Any nearby lights may flicker as 20A or more is drawn for a short amount of time.  Good test of the NTC (monitor temperature.)

Comment: @rdtsc I made the connections as the new attached photo and plugged it into 220V with the no-load condition but it exploded at the plug-in. the explosion happened in the sense resistor (R9 R10) the bridge rectifier is burned out and I think also the MOSFET. I have to mention that I didn't use the NTC in the circuit. what is my mistake? Is the problem the absence of the NTC?

Comment: The problem is most likely that a PCB (printed circuit board) wasn't used.  Each one of those wires has much more parasitic inductance and capacitance than a PCB trace does, which will affect the operation to a point where it no longer works (or even operates safely, as you unfortunately discovered.)  Look for a reference PCB design and make a board like that.

Comment: @rdtsc, Since the components used, are not yet finalized, isn't it technically possible for the circuit to operate with the same wiring at all? To postpone the PCB design to the next step

Comment: @rdtsc Also, regardless of PCB, is the presence of NTC critical for the correct operation of the circuit, or is it used only for extra protection?

Comment: It is possible for some circuits (DC or low-frequency), but not a PFC controller.  A PCB must be used (a solderless breadboard also is not a good idea.)  Without the NTC, how much current is drawn when connected?  Hint: capacitors resist change in voltage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135719/discussion-between-kmoradi-and-rdtsc).

Answer (score 1):

If you duplicated all the [details in the design](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4172985_Roadmap_Differentiation_and_Emerging_Trends_in_BCD_Technology) including parts and PCB layout, according to the datasheet with a low load;

> 9/16
> L6562
> When the load of a PFC pre-regulator is very low, the output voltage tends to stay steadily above the nominal value, which cannot be handled by the Dynamic OVP. If this occurs, however, the error amplifier output will saturate low; hence, when this is detected, the external power transistor is switched off and the IC put in an idle state (Static OVP). Normal operation is resumed as the error amplifier goes back into its linear region. As a result, the L6562 will work in burst-mode, with a repetition rate that can be very low.

So you should expect overvoltage to occur and Static OVP to be triggered although there can be situations where excess stress can occur without a line filter and line transients.

For more safety, I would add a dummy pre-load of 10% using any suitable fan cooled NPN load for 8W or a 20W resistor.  You can test the supply to 80W with an NPN active load if you design it for 150W so as to derate temp rise.  Use a Darlington with large heatsink and fan.